# Create combinations from list and remove if substring to delimiter characters is in more than 1 subelement of a list item

Tags: python, list, python-itertools

I have a list that I use itertools.combinations to create all combinations. The elements in each list item are able to be delimited by the string ": ". I need to remove list items where there is more than one occurrence of the same matched substring in more than 1 element. The characters in the string up until ": " (delimiter to use for regex match???) needs to check each sub-element in a list item. Or, is there a better way?

```
inList = [['TEST1: sub1'],
['TEST1: sub2'],
['TEST1: sub3'],
['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext'],
['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2'],
['ABC123: dog']]
outputList = list(combinations(inList,3))
outputList
```

I get this as a result:

```
[(['TEST1: sub1'], ['TEST1: sub2']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['TEST1: sub3']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['TEST1: sub3']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2'], ['ABC123: dog'])]
```

But I'd like to remove where substrings match sub-elements up until the delimiter ": ".

Desired output after sub-elements are checked for >1 occurrence in other sub-elements of a list item:

```
(['TEST1: sub1'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2'], ['ABC123: dog'])]
```

*Notice the first 2 items in the list are removed in the desired output? (this applied to others where the substring prior to `": "` occurs regardless of string length.

Comment: your code says 3 length combinations, but your provided example/output does not match, each element only has 2 length combinations. There definitely is a better way, but im not sure which approach you need here. Can you clarify?

Comment: @ Paritosh Singh You are a genius! Good catch, the 3 length I copy+paste is incorrect from a different desired result test. You are correct. I tested both lengths and got the desired result.  This is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the desired output is correct, then you can break this down into three separate steps:

First, The delimiter is representing a key value relationship, so you can just use a dictionary to group the data with same keys before doing any other operation.

Second, take as many `n` length combinations of the data with different keys.

Lastly, for each of those combinations, use itertools product to get all possible pairs within the combination.

```
from itertools import combinations, product
from collections import defaultdict

inList = [['TEST1: sub1'],
['TEST1: sub2'],
['TEST1: sub3'],
['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext'],
['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2'],
['ABC123: dog']]


inDict = defaultdict(list)
for lst in inList:
    key = lst[0].partition(':')[0]
    inDict[key].append(lst)

print(inDict)
#Output:
defaultdict(list,
            {'TEST1': [['TEST1: sub1'], ['TEST1: sub2'], ['TEST1: sub3']],
             'TESTING FOR FUN': [['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext'],
              ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']],
             'ABC123': [['ABC123: dog']]})


temp = combinations(inDict.values(), 2) #2 length pairs from all dict values. change the number here as needed
result = []
for group in temp:
    result.extend(product(*group)) #calculate all products for each pair of lists. 

print(result)
#Output:
[(['TEST1: sub1'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2']),
 (['TEST1: sub1'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TEST1: sub2'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TEST1: sub3'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TESTING FOR FUN: randomtext'], ['ABC123: dog']),
 (['TESTING FOR FUN: random text x2'], ['ABC123: dog'])]
```

Comment: Can you explain the asterisk (*) in ```result.extend(product(*group))```?

Comment: @Chris yep, that's called the unpacking operator. I am using it to unpack the tuple containing 2 lists before passing it into product. it effectively removes the tuple, and thus is similar to `product(group[0], group[1])` but is capable of dynamically unpacking as many arguments as passed. You may wish to read further online, say [here](https://codeyarns.com/2012/04/26/unpack-operator-in-python/) or some other resources.